# What is the origin of 火黑暗?

Tags: etymology, phrase, culture, history

What is the origin of [火黑暗](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huoheian)?

According to wikipedia it comes from the [Zangshu, "Book of Burial"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Burial), but no where in that book (or anywhere else) can I find this supposed phrase:

> "Qi vapors in the fire, and is lost in the darkness."

*(Whereas it's very easy to find the origin of the phrase Feng shui 風水 in the Zangshu)*

Comment: Never heard of it, nor can it be found in Chinese websites.

Comment: @TooskyHierot Yeah, me too. That's why I'm wondering if this tradition of aesthetics even existed.

Answer (score 4):

On the [talk](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Huoheian#Is_this_for_real?) page there is the following question:

> Is this for real?

which reads:

> I can't find any references to this supposed system anywhere outside of Wikipedia. A google search for 火黑暗 reveals nothing to do with architecture, aesthetics, or feng shui. Of the sources given on this page I can't find the Von Erdberg (1936) online, but I did find a preview of Cai (2004) on Google Books, and searching this book for "火黑暗", "huoeheian", "fire and darkness" gives nothing either. The Chinese language wikipedia does not have an article on this subject either. Does anyone have any more info on where this concept comes from? --83.216.95.30 (talk) 00:56, 31 January 2018 (UTC)

There's no response.

---

[This](https://fengshuigate.com/zangshu.html) seems to be Field's translation, supposedly it was revised July 26, 2009, I'm not sure if anything got changed or not, but there seems to be nothing akin to the Wikipeida quote.